# removeOnTabSelectedListener expression expected?

Tags: java, android, tabs, arguments, listener

I am trying to remove the `OnTabSelected` listener which I am using in `onNavigationItemSelected` block, but I keep getting an error message saying that an `experession is expected`. My code line is:

> tabsServices.removeOnTabSelectedListener(TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener);

Am I doing something wrong? What should I pass as an argument? I want to remove the listener, because the app goes to another fragment and is no longer needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass in the reference of your `TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener` the one that you've passed in `tabsServices.addOnTabSelectedListener` when you had set it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But could you clarify that a little bit more for me. Or maybe give me an example?

Comment: Actually, I found a very useful GitHub article which helped me understand what you meant. I am actually trying to do something different, but it helped me figure it out. Thanks for your help.
https://github.com/hidroh/materialistic/blob/master/app/src/main/java/io/github/hidroh/materialistic/widget/ItemPagerAdapter.java